# Novice error while simplifying boolean expression with XOR

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have the following expressions:

$x = a⊕b , y = c⊕d, z = x⊕y $

So 
$x = ab'+a'b,  y = cd'+c'd $

$z = xy'+x'y = (ab'+a'b) * (cd'+c'd)' + (ab'+a'b)'*(cd'+c'd)$

If I take the first term : $(ab'+a'b) * (cd'+c'd)' = (De Morgan) = (ab'+a'b) * c'dcd'$

Yet, $c'dcd'$ is false, so the first term is false.

Where is my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It's right below the list of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I take the first term : $(ab'+a'b) * (cd'+c'd)' = (De Morgan) = (ab'+a'b) * c'dcd'$
>
> Yet, $c'dcd'$ is false, so the first term is false.
>
> Where is my mistake?

Your mistake is in the DeMorgan:

It is not true that $(cd'+c'd)'=c'dcd'$

Rather:

$(cd'+dc')' = (cd')'(dc')' = (c'+d)(d'+c)$

Comment: So, If I've understood correctly, (cd′)′ != c'd and there's my problem.

Comment: @XristosK Correct! $(cd')'=c'+d$

Answer (score 1):

**if you're in a boolean algebra**

In a boolean algebra, $+$ denotes XOR already. $a \vee b$ corresponds to $a + b + ab$.

Besides (this may simplify your expressions nicely), the negation of $a$, which you write $a'$, is simply $1 + a$.

**if you want to handle a boolean expression**

There's a mistake in the de Morgan rule.

The first term is
$((a\wedge b')\vee (a'\wedge b)) \wedge ((c\wedge d')\vee (d'\wedge d))$
$ = [(a \wedge b') \wedge ((c\wedge d')\vee (c'\wedge d))] \vee  [(a' \wedge b) \wedge ((c\wedge d')\vee (c'\wedge d))]$
$$=(a \wedge b' \wedge c \wedge d')\vee (a \wedge b' \wedge c' \wedge d)\vee (a' \wedge b \wedge c \wedge d') \vee (a' \wedge b \wedge c' \wedge d)$$

Comment: + denotes OR and * denotes AND, XOR = ⊕.  Which expression can be simplified?

Comment: @XristosK One usually uses $\vee$ (\vee) for or, and $\wedge$ (\wedge) for and. You can use $\sqcup$ (\sqcup) for XOR .